# How to search for rows that contain a special word case in-sensitively in a specific column in DataFrames Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I was trying to find a specific dataset within `RDatasets` and since this package has provided 763 datasets with specific notations, it's hard to find out whether the dataset exists in the RDatasets. For example, I knew there exists a dataset that is about foods but I didn't know the exact name. So I searched for it to find out whether it's been provided by the `RDatasets`:

```
using RDatasets, DataFrames

# This line recalls information on all the provided datasets within the package
Rdatasets = RDatasets.datasets();

Rdatasets[occursin.("food", Rdatasets.Title), :]
# 0×5 DataFrame
#  Row │ Package   Dataset   Title   Rows   Columns
#      │ String15  String31  String  Int64  Int64
# ─────┴────────────────────────────────────────────

# Then I searched for "Food"
Rdatasets[occursin.("Food", Rdatasets.Title), :]
# 1×5 DataFrame
#  Row │ Package   Dataset     Title                              Rows   Columns
#      │ String15  String31    String                             Int64  Int64
# ─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#    1 │ Ecdat     BudgetFood  Budget Share of Food for Spanish…  23972        6
```

But I tried two times, and even I might give up on the further search. How can I find the row in the `Rdatasets` DataFrame that contains the food word case in-sensitively in its `Title` column (if there is any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx is everyone's friend! Even if you were looking for `Iris` in the `Dataset` column, you'd be in trouble because they provided the names case-sensitively. So **an option** is lower/upper case the contents of the preferred column using `lowercase.(df.columnname)` and then search for the word in the suitable corresponding matchcase (but this can fail in extreme cases, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971713/11747148)), **or you can use RegEx** and hand over it to decide about the occurrence of the letters! So the latter helps you to find the specific word within a specific column in any dataframe with its specific notations (for example, maybe you had a dataframe that contained iris with the specific notation of "iRiS" in its column. Then it wouldn't be efficient to search for `Iris` or `iris` or `iRis` etc. until one works):

```
Rdatasets[occursin.(r"(?i)food", Rdatasets.Title), :]
# 1×5 DataFrame
#  Row │ Package   Dataset     Title                              Rows   Columns
#      │ String15  String31    String                             Int64  Int64
# ─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#    1 │ Ecdat     BudgetFood  Budget Share of Food for Spanish…  23972        6
```

In the above, I used a RegEx expression to search for any notation of the food word within the `Title` column of the `Rdatasets` DataFrame. The `?(i)` turns case-insensitivity on and the `r""` is:

```
help?> r""
  @r_str -> Regex


  Construct a regex, such as r"^[a-z]*$", without interpolation and unescaping (except for quotation mark "      
  which still has to be escaped). The regex also accepts one or more flags, listed after the ending quote, to    
  change its behaviour:

    •  i enables case-insensitive matching

    •  m treats the ^ and $ tokens as matching the start and end of individual lines, as opposed to the
       whole string.

    •  s allows the . modifier to match newlines.

    •  x enables "comment mode": whitespace is enabled except when escaped with \, and # is treated as
       starting a comment.

    •  a disables UCP mode (enables ASCII mode). By default \B, \b, \D, \d, \S, \s, \W, \w, etc. match
       based on Unicode character properties. With this option, these sequences only match ASCII
       characters.

  See Regex if interpolation is needed.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> match(r"a+.*b+.*?d$"ism, "Goodbye,\nOh, angry,\nBad world\n")
  RegexMatch("angry,\nBad world")


  This regex has the first three flags enabled.
```

Note that things can be more complicated like occurring special chars ($, @, etc.), and in those cases converting the content to `uppercase` or the opposite wouldn't be helpful! So using RegEx is the safest option.

## Comparison

Comparison against [Przemyslaw's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971713/11747148):

```
julia> @benchmark $Rdatasets[occursin.(r"(?i)food", $Rdatasets.Title), :]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  120.000 μs … 583.000 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     125.200 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   135.361 μs ±  27.258 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▅█▆▅▄▃▃▂▂▁▃▃▂▁▁▁▂▁▁▁                                          ▁
  ███████████████████████▇▇▆▆▆▆▆▇▆▅▆▆▅▅▅▆▆▆▅▆▅▆▆▅▅▅▄▄▅▃▅▆▆▄▅▅▄▅ █
  120 μs        Histogram: log(frequency) by time        265 μs <

 Memory estimate: 5.81 KiB, allocs estimate: 27.

julia> @benchmark $Rdatasets[occursin.(Unicode.normalize("food",casefold=true), Unicode.normalize.($Rdatasets.Title,casefold=true)),:]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 4393 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  984.700 μs …  10.233 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 88.07%
 Time  (median):       1.064 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):     1.132 ms ± 463.506 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.15% ±  4.81%

    ▂▅█▅▂                                                        
  ▂▃██████▇▅▅▅▄▄▄▃▄▄▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▂▁▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▁▁▂ ▃
  985 μs           Histogram: frequency by time         1.76 ms <

 Memory estimate: 268.03 KiB, allocs estimate: 3085.
```

If I want to sumup:

|  | Time | Memory | Garbage Collect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| using RegEx | ~135.361 μs | ~5.81 KiB, allocs: 27 | 0% |
| using `Unicode.normalize` | ~1.132 ms | ~268.03 KiB, allocs: 3085 | 2.15% ± 4.81 |

Answer (score 1):

According to Julia documentation, [`Unicode.normalize("", casefold=true)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Unicode/#Unicode.normalize) is recommended to perform case-insensitive comparison.

Hence you want:

```
julia> Rdatasets[occursin.(Unicode.normalize("food",casefold=true), Unicode.normalize.(Rdatasets.Title,casefold=true)),:]
1×5 DataFrame
 Row │ Package   Dataset     Title                              Rows   Columns
     │ String15  String31    String                             Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Ecdat     BudgetFood  Budget Share of Food for Spanish…  23972        6
```

Example when this matters over `lowercase` (two ways to write "foot" in German):

```
julia> Unicode.normalize("der Fuß",casefold=true) == 
    Unicode.normalize("der Fuss",casefold=true)
true

julia> lowercase("der Fuß") == lowercase("der Fuss")
false
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't see any recommendations there :( But this isn't robust and is verbose and needs making the same operation on both sides of the `occursin` function. Also, it's slower. I'll append the comparison in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is slower but is guaranteed to perform comparisons correctly across all Unicode characters. There is quite a lot of discussions on `lowercase` vs `casefold` but for other programming languages and I think they make good point. I added one example.

Comment: This can be handled by using RegEx as well. Okay, I got you. you're making a comparison against `lowercase` and `casefold`. Thanks.

Comment: In German `"ß"` and `"ss"` are the same character and hence you need `casefold`. And I guess  there are more such languages. And that is the reason for `casefold` to be slower because it does more complicated stuff. Still in most cases `lowercase` will do the job but only if you know why you are not using `casefold`.

Comment: Thanks for this point! So I'll refer to this answer for the reason behind the drawback of `lowercase`/`uppercase` in extreme cases. Thank you so much 